# What's the difference between these two functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Type 1 :

```
var EXAMPLE = function() {};
```

Type 2:

```
var EXAMPLE = function($) {
    return {};
}(jQuery);
```

I'm JavaScript beginner and trying to understand the difference between these two piece of code. In functionality wise I didn't see the difference when I tried to add a property to the EXAMPLE object.

Comment: One difference is that the first is plain, vanilla Javascript, while the second uses a widely known library called [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: They use the same variable name. Other then that almost everything else is different.

Comment: first EXAMPLE holds a `function` object. seconnd EXAMPLE holds a plain `object {}` which is returned by the 2nd function execution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple of major differences there:

1. With the first one, the value of `EXAMPLE` ends up being a function object. With the second one, it ends up being a plain object (not a function), because in the second one, the function is being *called* and you're storing its return value (the `{}`) in `EXAMPLE`.
2. The second one relies on your having a `jQuery` symbol defined (probably as a result of including jQuery on the page). The first doesn't.

So they're pretty different.

The first is a pretty generic way of creating a function (in this case, a function that doesn't do anything).

The second is a fairly standard way to use jQuery without relying on the `$` global (because sometimes people use `jQuery.noConflict()` to release the `$` symbol). The idea is that since `jQuery` is being passed into the function as the `$` argument, *within* the function code can use `$` even though there is no `$` *global*. People routinely do this and return an object with functions on it, like this:

```js
jQuery.noConflict(); // Release $
display("typeof $ = " + typeof $);   // "undefined"

var EXAMPLE = function($) {
  return {
    red: function(selector) {
      // Note we can use $ here, even though $ isn't
      // defined globally
      $(selector).css("color", "red");
    },
    green: function(selector) {
      $(selector).css("color", "green");
    }
  };
}(jQuery);

setTimeout(function() {
  EXAMPLE.red("#target");
}, 700);

setTimeout(function() {
  EXAMPLE.green("#target");
}, 1400);

function display(msg) {
  jQuery("<p>").html(String(msg)).appendTo(document.body);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target">I'm the target element</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This example create function and assign it to `Example`

```
var EXAMPLE = function() {};
```

This RUN function and assign object returned by function `Example = {b: jQuery}`

```
var EXAMPLE = function($) {
    return {b: $};
}(jQuery);
```